# Parallaxing effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created two scroll views with a panel between them in unity. Inside the inner scroll view I have an image I was trying to bring the functionality that when I scroll the foreground scroll view than the background scroll view is also scrolled but at a different speed. How can I accomplish this.

Comment: Do you use the old GUI system or new UI system?

Comment: I am using new UI system

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use a `Orthographic` camera and attach this script to your background. Best thing to do would be to have several background sprites parallel and reset there positions to visible to the moving camera.

```
void Update()
  {
    // Movement
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(
      speed.x * direction.x,
      speed.y * direction.y,
      0);

    movement *= Time.deltaTime;
    transform.Translate(movement);

    // Move the camera
    if (isLinkedToCamera)
    {
      Camera.main.transform.Translate(movement);
    }
  }
```

If you need step by step advices to get things done [tutorial by pixelnest](http://pixelnest.io/tutorials/2d-game-unity/parallax-scrolling/) may be useful.

Comment: See I have a transparent sprite with a scroll view on it (foreground).After this I have added a panel and then a second sprite with a texture and a scroll view on it(background).Actually what i want is when i drag my first view then the background image also gets dragged but with lesser speed. This functionality is very similar to the one used in smartphones. And I am just trying to implement it using New UI system.

Comment: If I an get some help with this

Comment: Yeah I get it (but better to update your question with what you have tried).
So if you already have a script to make the scrolling effect you can do it right? just use a parameter for `speed` and attach it to those layers and change the speed on the editor

Comment: sir i am trying this but both of the layers are unable to move simultaneously. I am unable to understand what i am missing.